# Background-clip и background-origin - в чем разница?

Tags: html, css

`background-clip` и `background-origin` - в чем разница? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разница в следующем:

`background-origin` помещает фоновое изображение в соответствии со значением свойства.

`background-clip` **ОБРЕЗАЕТ** фоновое изображение или фоновый цвет в соответствии со значением свойства. Если фоновое изображение *было прижато к внешнему краю* border-а, то будет показана **только та** часть изображения которая находится внутри border (`border-box`) или внутри border+padding (`content-box`). Если задано значение `padding-box`, то будет вся картинка целиком.

В общем, пример тут:  `https://jsfiddle.net/q86uk2kh/embedded/result/`

Comment: Я так понимаю, что при *border-box* будет показана вся картинка *background*-a (хотя ее часть будет не видима (Если *border:solid с прозрачностью в 1*), т.к. находится под *border*-ом). При *padding-box* будет обрезана часть картинки которая находится под *border*, а остальная часть картинки, которая находится в зоне *padding* и *content* будет видима. А при *content-box* обрезается вся часть картинки *background*-a кроме той, что находится в зоне контента. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Совершенно верно. Только учтите, что это работает, если сочетать оба свойства `background-origin: border-box;` и `background-clip`.